# Как использовать process.env в файлах приложения Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

Объясните мне, пожалуйста, как я могу задействовать, например, `process.env.NODE_ENV` непосредственно в коде Vue.js приложения.

Я уточню что имею ввиду не конфиги Webpack'а, а непосредственно файл `main.js` из:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
```

Читал https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/, но ничего не понял. Очень скудные примеры, которые дальше конфигов Webpack не уходят (хотя у них есть пример `SERVICE_URL`, что очень странно выглядит). На одном [форуме](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/where-to-keep-env-configuration/23070/6) видел фразу, мол, с помощью DefinePlugin можно использовать переменные окружения прямо в коде файлов приложения, но опять же никаких примеров, а у меня ничего не получилось. Переменная `process` или `NODE_ENV` в коде приложения недоступна - отображает критическую ошибку: `'process' is not defined`.

С помощью `process.env` я хочу передавать, например, в файл `main.js` данные для `Vue.config`. Или тот же `SERVICE_URL`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2):

DefinePlugin тут может помочь, в конфиге вебпака:

```
 plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'SERVICE_URL': JSON.stringify('http://some_url'),
            }
        })
 ]
```

И далее используем в коде: `process.env.SERVICE_URL`

Comment: Так я же написал, что так и делаю. Но в коде ошибка, мол, `'process' is not defined`.

Comment: Я понимаю что код, который вы привели, вроде бы как по идее должен передавать `process.env` в код приложения. Да и люди пишут об этом в интернетах. Но почему тогда я ловлю критическую ошибку? Приложение Vue.js собирал из их шаблонов. То есть конфиги Webpack собирал не с нуля, да и не переписывал их сильно, особенно в подобной сфере, как взаимодействие с env.

Comment: Думаю, здесь без реального кода врятли что-то скажешь. Возможно данный плагин в вашем конфиге не используется, например, для dev сборки или наоборот. Но тут не угадаешь)